# problem comparing two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I m using below query from c# to compare current date with date stored in database as string.but it do not show the proper output even though it is not showing any error.

```
Select * from tblconcertdetail 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Concert_Date,'%m/%d/%Y')>="+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+";
```

first argument shows as: 2011-06-10
second shows ; 2011-06-02

it shows all rows of table

Comment: What happens if you directly input the date that you are comparing the STR_TO_DATE output to, e.g., STR_TO_DATE(...) >= '2011-06-02'

Comment: Have you tried: Select * from tblconcertdetail 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Concert_Date,'%m/%d/%Y')>= curdate()   ?

Comment: `Concert_Date` is a date/datetime/timestamp?

Comment: PS: `2011-06-10` is greater than/equal to `2011-06-02`. This row should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the first argument returns as you said YYYY-MM-DD???? Make sure the value for "Concert_Date" should look like "04/22/2011".

Try the following:

```
Select * from tblconcertdetail where date(Concert_Date) >= "+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+";
```

I think Concert_Date is of datatype "date" or "datetime" or "timestamp".

Comment: no i have taken Concert_Date as string type for easyness at time of inserting data

Comment: @user755230: if it were possible to downvote a comment I would have done so!

Answer (score 0):

The output of `STR_TO_DATE(Concert_Date,'%m/%d/%Y')` depends on `Concert_Date`.
Its different values will produce different results if compared to the second date.

I think you should try to use this portion of code:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2011-06-10','%Y-%m-%d');
```

IMHO if `Concert_Date` is equal to `2011-06-10` you cannot read it correctly with `'%m/%d/%Y'` patern.